# Compatibility between py2exe and GDAL for the creation of an executable file

Tags: python, compatibility, executable, py2exe, gdal

My target is to produce a small executable (.exe) file to read [shapefile](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapefile) format and do same easy processing. Before starting to code, I wish to know if the "[OGR Simple Feature Library](https://gdal.org/programs/index.html#vector-programs)" (The OGR Simple Features Library is a C++ open source library providing read access to a variety of vector file formats including ESRI Shapefiles, inside GDAL) is compatible with [py2exe](https://www.py2exe.org/).

I know there is a pure python library to read [shapefile](https://code.google.com/archive/p/pyshp) format, but the library can read only the external boundary and not the internals (i.e., holes).

Comment: This might be helpful from GIS.Stackexchange http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/34743/how-can-i-use-py2exe-with-the-osgeo4w-python-installation